# combine dates into another column in r

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset where treatment1_bcr is the object of interest. it has 2 levels 0 = no and 1 = yes and some missing values NA. So I have been trying to make a separate column of dates last_visit_date. The new column is associated with treatment1_bcr where if treatment1_bcr = 0 take the corresponding date from lastpsa_date,  if treatment1_bcr=1 take the corresponding date from treatment1_bcrdate, and if treatment1_bcr=NA then take the corresponding date from pro_date. Here is a sample of the dataset. The empty spaces are as is in the dataset. The size of the dataset is >2000 rows.

| treatment1_bcr | pro_date | lastpsa_date | treatment1_bcrdate | last_visit_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10/8/2020 |  |  | 10/8/2020 |
| 1 |  |  | 10/19/2015 | 10/19/2015 |
| NA |  | 6/9/2014 |  | 6/9/2014 |

The column last_date_visit should look like the example.

Here is what I have been trying out unsuccessfully . I am using lubridate and dplyr ,

last_visit_date<-as.character(ifelse(Prostatectomy$treatment1_bcr == 1 , as.character (Prostatectomy$treatment1_bcrdate),
ifelse (Prostatectomy$treatment1_bcr == 0, as.character(Prostatectomy$lastpsa_date), as.character(Prostatectomy$pro_date)))).

Thanks.

Comment: try dplyr::case_when - much better than nested ifelse statements. Use with dplyr::mutate

Comment: could you please give an example. Thanks

Comment: `df %>%mutate(last_visit_dat=coalesce(!!!across(-1, na_if,'')))`

Comment: i am getting an error Error in local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = i, mask = mask) : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

Comment: If you use coalesce, you can name the columns  `df |> mutate(last_visit_dat = coalesce(pro_date, lastpsa_date, treatment1_bcrdate))`

Comment: Hi . There has been an issue. I can see that the column gets added to the dataset in R, but when I try to write the dataset into excel or view the dataset in the viewer pane, the column isnt present. Could you please help me with this issue.